# How to get textContent to work in Internet Explorer 8 (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have applied a textContent to a div in JavaScript. I cannot get it to work in Internet Explorer. How can I get it to work in Internet Explorer 8. I tried doing :

`<div id="price"></div>`

and:

`document.getElementById("price").textContent = "GMGo is $5.00";`

but it didn't show the text "GMGo is $5.00"

Comment: Why are nobody answering me and everybody down voting.

Comment: What version are you using? According to [this]( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent), maybe you're using an older version and that's why it isn't working?

Comment: Lack of examples, lack of exception message, weasel words ("apply", "it", "work"), unclear target IE version (`textContent` support added in IE9), all contribute to this being a bad question.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that

Comment: I have windows XP and cannot use IE 9 or 10

Comment: Show some code. Edit your question rather than replying in the comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ie8 does not support `textContent`, but there is a way to fake it:

http://eligrey.com/blog/post/textcontent-in-ie8

```
if (Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor &&
     Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "textContent") &&
    !Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "textContent").get)
  (function() {
    var innerText = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "innerText");
    Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "textContent",
      { // It won't work if you just drop in innerText.get
        // and innerText.set or the whole descriptor.
        get : function() {
          return innerText.get.call(this)
        },
        set : function(x) {
          return innerText.set.call(this, x)
        }
      }
    );
  })();
```

Comment: Thank you! There isn't much well-written documentation on this kind of thing, but it's nice to see it done to at least see how `get` and `set` are used in JS. Woohoo for still supporting IE8!

Comment: @phatskat it's a strange situation where IE supported innerText, FF supported textContent, and Chrome supported both

Comment: Note while webkit support both, innerText and textContent have slightly different values.  textContent will contain whitespace from between the HTML elements, where innerText will not.